# Query with multiple where conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

hope someone can help me to understand why this first query works while the second one does not.
My goal is to show first the row with status "close" and then the row with status "wait"

```
 "SELECT *  from job WHERE status='close' AND status='wait' ";

 "SELECT *  from job WHERE status='close ";
```

I attempted to do this which is working but i want to show all status except "deleted"

```
$sql = "SELECT id,date, device,model,problem,status,assigned  from job  ORDER BY FIELD(status,'deler_trenger','deler_bestilt','new','progress','wait','done','close','cancel')";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use where condition with `status<>'deleted'`

```
SELECT id,date, device,model,problem,status,assigned  from job  
where status<>'deleted'
ORDER BY FIELD(status,'deler_trenger','deler_bestilt','new','progress','wait','done','close','cancel')
```

Comment: This is working, thank you. I was able to sort the Status as i liked but could not omit one of them.

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing single quote after `'close`. Also, try using `status!='deleted'` or `status<>'deleted'`.

Comment: I don't see that missing quote that you mention.

Comment: Missing quote is my error in the post, that is actually working.